# mailto: Internet explorer reversing timestring in outlook when email is created

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, outlook, internet-explorer-11, mailto

mailto: Internet explorer reversing timestring in outlook
I checked the generated href string it has correct timestring, its when internet explorer hands over to the outlook the timestring gets reversed. I tried replacing `:` seperator with other symbols like `.` or`,` etc.. but still it was reversing, when any alphabet is used as separator then it was not reversing e.g. 11t02t54AM with `new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/\:/g,"t")`.

Please let me know, if anyone knows why its reversing timestamp & any way to stop reversing.

> **output in chrome**
>
> Hi, I have recently visited, 
>           https://stacksnippets.net/js at 11:02:54 AM

And

> **output in Internet Explorer 11**
>
> Hi, I have recently visited, 
>           https://stacksnippets.net/js at 54:02:11AM

Time is correct but in reverse order: `seconds:minutes:hour`

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var emailToSend = "mailto:to@email.com?cc=cc@email.com&subject=subject&body=" + encodeURIComponent("Hi, I have recently visited, " + "\n\t" + location.href + " at " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + "\r\n"+"Thanks,"+"\r\n\n\t");

  var emailLink = document.createElement("a");
  emailLink.href = emailToSend;
  console.log(emailToSend);
  emailLink.click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sendEmail()"> Send Email </button>
```

Sample console output of href string with TimeStamp 11:56:50 PM

In chrome

```
mailto:to@email.com?cc=cc@email.com&subject=subject&body=Hi%2C%20I%20have%20recently%20
visited%2C%20%0A%09https%3A%2F%2Fstacksnippets.net%2Fjs%20
at%2011%3A56%3A50%20PM%0D%0AThanks%2C%0D%0A%0A%09
```

In Internet explorer

```
11%3A56%3A50%20PM%0D%0A
```

this part as in chrome output above, is constructed differently, same timestamp number's order but different long encoding characters.

Comment: It only happens when you create a `mailto:` URL? What happens if you just do `console.log(new Date().toLocaleString())`?

Comment: Yes, If you check the console.log, we can see same string is generated but opened why Internet explorer it reverses timestring.

Comment: If you want predictable date formatting, you should format it yourself, maybe using `moment.js`.

Comment: I dont think formatting is issue, the dates format well & same, its the encoding of timestamp in internet explorer causing some issue & reversing timestring. Surprising thing is only numbers are in reverse order, the meridian(AM/PM) is staying in order.

Comment: The way the Date object is converted to a string is formatting. You're using the browser's built-in format, but you could control it fully if you create the string yourself.

Comment: yes, I decided to use 24 hour format with timezone, but I am just curious why Internet explorer encoding timestamp differently & why that is causing it to reverse the time stamp.

Comment: IE does lots of curious things.

Comment: Haha.. true that.. I would have ignored if it was Internet explorer 8/9 but in 11 also.

Comment: Found in some post: The problem is that the dates for some reason contains lots of U+200E "LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK" characters (which are invisible, but still present), which once encoded become %E2%80%8E.

Comment: Sounds like something in your environment is telling the browser that you're using a right-to-left language.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like time format on your computer is set as **Seconds : minutes : hours (ss:mm:hh tt)**.

For testing purpose, i try to change the time format on my machine and made a test with IE and chrome.

Below is the testing result.

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Internet Explorer:**

[image]

To solve the issue, you need to change the time format on your machine by setting customized format or by choosing any other default format from Clock and region settings.

[image]

Output in IE after setting custom format for time.

[image]

**Note that time will display in a format which had set on that specific machine. So if you run this code on any other machine and if that machine has any other format than it will be displayed in that format.**

Comment: thanks for replying, Yes also thought so but when I checked the time format it was just the default one & still I was getting timestamp reversed. Checked on others system also, same. I even tried setting different formats from control panel, but same issue. Its the encoding of timestamp in internet explorer by encodeURIComponent causing some issue & reversing timestring. Surprising thing is only numbers are in reverse order, the meridian(AM/PM) is staying in order.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about your environment like OS version and IE 11 version? Which region is set? Does changing the region and date format to English US made some change in result? For testing purpose, try to reset the date and time format to see whether it helps or not.

Comment: yes.. I did change the format like in your post to custom formats also.. Its latest internet explorer 11.. windows 10.. Actually I saw in one post that in Internet explorer 11, `encodeURIComponent` encodes date-time string with diff characters than other browsers & that could be reason.

Comment: Found in some post: The problem is that the dates for some reason contains lots of U+200E "LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK" characters (which are invisible, but still present), which once encoded become %E2%80%8E.

Comment: To verify that encodeURIComponent is the actual culprit, can you please remove it from your code and again try to run the code to see whether it is showing the time in proper format or not? It can help to decide the cause for the issue.

Comment: yeah.. you are correct.. its not directly the encodeURIComponent.. tried without encodeURIComponent.. and still it was reversing the timestamp.. Like that post I think its `toLocalTimeString()` that is adding the "invisible" characters "RIGHT-TO-LEFT" in Internet Explorer 11 to outlook data exchange